# passing javascript array to server only retrieves the last element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am using jQuery and PHP. I have a JavaScript `array`, when I pass it to the server and try to retrieve the array, I can only get the last element. Why is that and how can I get my array values properly?

**JavaScript:**

```
var arr = [] ;
arr.push("kanishka");
arr.push("bandara");

jQuery.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: baseurl+"profile/mprofile/action/ratings/add_ratings",
  data:{ "arr":arr},
  success: function(data, status) {  
    jQuery('#header-error').html(data);
  } 
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$arr = $this->ci->input->post('arr');
pre($arr); 
die;
```

**Result shown in FireBug:**

```
<pre>bandara</pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = [] ;
arr.push("kanishka");
arr.push("bandara");

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: baseurl+"profile/mprofile/action/ratings/add_ratings",
    data:{ "arr":arr.serializeArray()},
    success: function(data, status) {  

        jQuery('#header-error').html(data);
    } 
});
```

Comment: mm. it did not worked since i am using jquery 1.3.2 . i used JSON.stringify insted , thanks any way.